# How to access Request Monitor in IIS Server Manager?

Tags: http, iis, logging, servermanager

I've just installed the "Request Monitor" role in "Server Manager",

[image: request monitor]

hoping that I could watch all the HTTP requests come in and go out. Now how do I access this tool? I've never used this software before and I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Thank you for asking this (and posting the screenshot.) I had the reverse problem; I have used the action in the past but didn't realize there was a feature that needed to be installed to use it. I had no actions in the pane and needed to install the feature you referenced.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

From https://portal.ektron.com/KB/10396/:

Find the "Worker Process" icon on the server settings in IIS Manager.

[image]

Comment: I did all these but when i go to the requests, the list is empty.I have like 50 requests per minute so the list should be full. Is a server restart needed in order to work?

Comment: Same here - busy server but empty lists for all active application pools!

Comment: The list should usually be empty unless you have slow response times. 50/minute is about 1100 between requests, and most requests are served in 200ms or less, so 80% of the time it should be empty

Comment: @GarrGodfrey Yeah, I'm at like 300 requests/sec and still under 5% cpu utilization.

Answer (score 12):

From the article on [View Currently Executing Requests in a Worker Process (IIS 7)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732518%28v=ws.10%29.aspx):

> 1. Open IIS Manager. For information about opening IIS Manager, see Open IIS Manager (IIS 7). For information about navigating to locations in the UI, see Navigation in IIS Manager (IIS 7).
> 2. In the **Connections** pane, select the server node in the tree.
> 3. In **Features View**, double-click **Worker Processes**.
> 4. Select a worker process from the grid. *Note that only running worker processes show up here, so you may need to launch the desired one by issuing a request.*
> 5. Click **View Current Requests** in the **Actions** pane.
> 6. View the list of requests in the grid.

Comment: These instructions are for IIS 7. Request Monitor is for IIS 8, which doesn't have the connections pane.